# Prevent Newly Submitted On Demand Resources From Overwriting Older Versions iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, on-demand-resources

I'm using iOS ODRs to distribute various content to my app. I'm running into an issue that if I make adjustments to these asset bundles and release an update to my app, the older versions of the app will be downloading those new asset bundles as well, but the older version of the app isn't designed to work with them so it will get errors.

For some backstory: I'm using ODRs to distribute Unity Scenes as assetbundles. Because iOS is Ahead Of Time Compilation, I have to include a base Unity scene with the app from download so that when I load one of the assetbundles it has all of the necessary scripts already in the app. The issue is if I make a change to a script in one of the scenes, I need to rebuild the unity project and embed it in the iOS project and resubmit to the app store with the new asset bundles as well. The issue is after I make a change to one of those scripts, the new asset bundles might not work on the older versions of the app that don't contain that script change.

Is there a way I can keep versions of the assetbundles and have different versions of my app download their corresponding assetbundle?

Thanks!